# Add Action after drag and drop in JTable

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable, action

I have a JTable that allows reordering of rows via drag-and-drop. I need to execute an action after a row is dropped. I initially used a mouse listener and use mouseReleased() to perform my action, but that executes before the order of the rows has technically changed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have done similar task before but in my case I have to render the row color after the drop.

AFAIK there is nothing to do with `MouseListener`.

If you are implementing [TransferHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html) methods then in the [importData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html#importData%28javax.swing.TransferHandler.TransferSupport%29) method we will insert row in to the target table. Here if the row insertion is success then just call the method which does `reordering of rows` in the target table.